# Can I use a string as an Id?

Tags: java, android

Still a Noob at Android Development..
So here's My Code

```
for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){
    for(int j=startat;j<=7;j++){
        String constring = "r" + i + "c" + j;
        //TextView dtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.constring); #commented this out
    }
}
```

Is there a way I could use the string variable constring as an Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to obtain resource id from name.

Comment: Here's a full example: int id = getResources().getIdentifier("r" + i + "c" + j, "id", this.getPackageName()); TextView dtv = (TextView) findViewById(id);

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I could use the string variable constring as an Id?

I'm little confused what are trying to make?!

This: `TextView dtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.constring);`

especially `R.id.constring` you shouldn't, musn't do it in the way you do. Every `id` is automatic generated from `XML` resources and you should respect it!

Also **R.id.costring** is `int` auto-generated in `R.java` not `String` so your approach won't work.

From your code is feel "spaghetti code".

```
<TextView 
   android:id=@+id/constring"
   ... next attributes
/>
```

If you'll write this, `id` named as **constring** will be automatic generated and then you just call `R.id` so **constring** is automatic filled.

It a case if you don't want to create `XML` so you just do it like that:

```
TextView t = new TextView();
t.setText("Hello World");
setContentView(t);
```

I recommend to you read some Android tutorials for beginners. Here you can start:

- [`Android - A beginner's
  guide`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102065/Android-A-beginner-s-guide)

Comment: Actually I'm creating a test app right now....I have created an xml layout with a 7x6 table on an activity and the textviews in it has the Id's of r1c1 r1c2 r1c3 r1c4 and so on....(r standing for row and c for column) so instead of accessing each cell one by one with a specific starting cell at the first row how would I change each cell values in a loop? is there a way that I could use constring to become the Id?

Comment: you will access to each cell without loop...your approach is dirty and not safe! and you should now that `id.costring` is `int` not `String` so your solution won't work.